# How can an epidural affect the labour and childbirth process?

Tags: risks, birth, c-section, epidural, obstetrician

I've heard that epidurals can slow down labour and even stall it. I've also heard that it can cause complications and increases the risk of c-section.

Comment: Heard from whom?